# Posting multiple questions for the same code at different points in the development

Tags: discussion

Here's the scenario:

I have posted a question on Code Review and received feedback (but not a refactored code). I **improve my code** based on the advice I was given in this question and **added new features** (e.g. code handles more cases).

I would love to have this new code reviewed for me, so my question is:

Should I:

1. **Edit my initial question** by appending the code in
2. **Answer my initial question** with this new code so I can get another answer
3. **Post a brand new question**: with a *"this is version two of my code seen here"*

It seems **1.** is against the site's guidelines because a question's code should never be altered, does adding new code (another version) later counts as so? **2.** doesn't seem very natural: even if I'm, in a way, providing an answer to my code with a refactored/expanded version I don't know If this is actually an answer.

This leaves me with **3.** What should I do? Am I allowed to post my code on <s>every</s> some of my code revisions to get some feedback?